# Clojure read CSV and split the columns into several vectors

Tags: csv, vector, clojure, split

Currently i have functions like this:

```
(def csv-file (.getFile  (clojure.java.io/resource "datasources.csv")))

(defn process-csv [file]
  (with-open [in-file (io/reader file)]
    (doall (csv/read-csv in-file))))
```

what i need to do now is to produce vectors based on / group by columns from csv, i.e my `process-csv` output looks like this:

```
(["atom" "neutron" "photon"] 
[10 22 3] 
[23 23 67])
```

my goal is to generate 3 vectors from column atom, neutron & photon:

```
atom: [10 23]
neutron: [22 23]
photon: [3 67]
```

FYI, i define 3 empty vectors before read the csv file:

```
(def atom [])
(def neutron[])
(def photon[])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first of all you can't modify these vectors, you've defined. It's the nature of immutable data structures. If you really need mutable vectors, use `atom`.

you can solve your task this way:

```
user> (def items (rest '(["atom" "neutron" "photon"] 
                         [10 22 3] 
                         [23 23 67]
                         [1 2 3]
                         [5 6 7])))

user> (let [[atom neutron photon] (apply map vector items)]
        {:atom atom :neutron neutron :photon photon})
{:atom [10 23 1 5], :neutron [22 23 2 6], :photon [3 67 3 7]}
```

that is how it work: 
`(apply map vector items)` equals the following:

`(map vector [10 22 3] [23 23 67] [1 2 3] [5 6 7])`

it takes first items of each coll and make a vector of them, then second items and so on.

also, you can make it more robust, by taking row column names exactly from your csv data header:

```
user> (def items '(["atom" "neutron" "photon"] 
                   [10 22 3] 
                   [23 23 67]
                   [1 2 3]
                   [5 6 7]))
#'user/items

user> (zipmap (map keyword (first items))
              (apply map vector (rest items)))
{:atom [10 23 1 5], :neutron [22 23 2 6], :photon [3 67 3 7]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not an universal solution. The keywords are hardcoded here.

Comment: They aren't in the last listing

Comment: Excuse me, my bad

Answer (score 1):

I'll illustrate some other methods you could use, which can be combined with methods that leetwinski illustrates.  Like leetwinski, I'll suggest using a hash map as your final structure, rather than three symbols containing vectors.  That's up to you.

If you want, you can use core.matrix's `transpose` to do what leetwinski does with `(apply map vector ...)`:

```
(require '[clojure.core.matrix :as mx])
(mx/transpose '(["atom" "neutron" "photon"] [10 22 3] [23 23 67]))
```

which produces:

```
[["atom" 10 23] ["neutron" 22 23] ["photon" 3 67]]
```

`transpose` is designed to work on any kind of matrix that implements the core.matrix protocols, and normal Clojure sequences of sequences are treated as matrices by core.matrix.

To generate a map, here's one approach:

```
(into {} (map #(vector (keyword (first %)) (rest %))
              (mx/transpose '(["atom" "neutron" "photon"] [10 22 3] [23 23 67]))))
```

which produces:

```
{:atom (10 23), :neutron (22 23), :photon (3 67)}
```

`keyword` makes strings into keywords.  `#(vector ...)` makes a pair, and `(into {} ...)` takes the sequence of pairs and makes a hash map from them.

Or if you want the vectors in vars, as you specified, then you can use a variant of leetwinski's `let` method.  I suggest not `def`ing the symbol `atom`, because that's the name of a standard function in Clojure.

```
(let [[adam neutron proton] (mx/transpose 
                              (rest '(["atom" "neutron" "photon"]
                                      [10 22 3]
                                      [23 23 67])))]
  (def adam adam)
  (def neutron neutron)
  (def proton proton))
```

It's not exactly good form to  use `def` inside a `let`, but you can do it.  Also, I don't recommend naming the local variables defined by `let` with the same names as the top-level variables.  As you can see, if makes the `def`s confusing.  I did this on purpose here just to show how the scoping rule works: In `(def adam adam)`, the first instance of "adam" represents the top-level variable that gets defined, whereas the second instance of "adam" represents the local var defined by `let`, containing `[10 23]`.  The result is:

```
  adam ;=> [10 23]
  neutron ;=> [22 23]
  proton ;=> [3 67]
```

(I think there are probably some subtleties that I'm expressing incorrectly.  If so, someone will no doubt comment about it.)